# How Jenkins Extended choice parameter plugin used with java and configfile.properties?

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

i am new to jenkins, I am trying to use jenkins extended choice parameter plugin with selenium project, where in my java code i have written options of driver and platform
Example:

```
TestCaseDriver("firefox", "grid", "LINUX");

TestCaseDriver("chrome", "grid", "LINUX");
```

if i use properties file to define these parameters,

```
TestCaseDriver("p.getProperties(browser)", "p.getProperties(driver)", "p.getProperties(platfrom)");
```

for Example: in config.properties browser=chrome,firefox  and platform=LINUX,WINDOWS

Jenkins can identify them if i use extended choice parameter plugin i can build with parameters but how java code will know that i am passing these parameters, as in the p.getProperties(browser) it will return chrome,firefox instead of a single browser

I need exactly how to use Extended choice parameter plugin in jenkins, with path of a given Config.properties  and how java code should be written to get that value

If we can use maven, please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question then I'd like to solve you problem by externalizing the required parameters. I'd like to use maven or ant to run the code with required parameters.For an example the build.xml (ant) which I'll create to externalize the parameter would contain:

```
    <target name="run" depends="compile-sdk, compile-tests">
    <property name="suite" value="*"/>
    <testng classpath="${classpath}" failureProperty="buildFailed">
        <xmlfileset dir="${testng.suites}" includes="testng.xml"/>
        <!-- Properties that can be changed through the command line -->
        <env key="browser.name" value="${browser.name}"/>
    </testng>
    </target>
```

Where `browser.name` is the parameter which gets externailze and to pass its value while running use `ant run -Dbrowser.name = Chrome` command. To get the property value in code I'll use:

```
// Method to create web driver instance depending upon parameter value
public void createWebDriverInstance(){
    String browserName = System.getenv("browser.name");
        if(browserName.contains("Chrome") || browserName.equals("Chrome")){
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
 }
```

You can use above approach to externalize the parameter and If I am not wrong you must be using some property file to store all the parameter which you want to pass. [Have a detailed look for Jenkins here.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)

Comment: It worked For me, by using this idea i changed my jenkins and i can build my parameterized builds